# cant load the image from sqlite database in android

Tags: android, database, sqlite, blob

I tried to load an image from an database but the image is not loading,the logcat shows null 
is it simethinf with the way i programmed..

```
imgdisplay = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgIcon);
myDB = this.openOrCreateDatabase("hello", MODE_PRIVATE, null);

Cursor c = myDB.rawQuery(
    "SELECT image  FROM employee_details WHERE name= 'vv'", null);

if (c.getCount() > 0) {
    c.moveToFirst();
    do {
        byte[] blob = c.getBlob(c.getColumnIndex("image"));
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgIcon);
        iv.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(blob, 0,blob.length));
    } while (c.moveToNext());
}
c.close();
myDB.close();
```

Logcat error is...

```
08-02 04:51:25.471: D/skia(8433): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
```

Comment: have you checked your table returns byte array??

Comment: @ArmaanStranger can u give me the code for doing that????

Comment: check your database buddy. is there any image data in "image" column for name "vv".

Comment: @ArmaanStranger
yes..
it shows [B@40d12280

Comment: only this much string it shows???

Comment: @ArmaanStranger
yes,is it something wrong with the encoding...

Comment: Yes i think you should use base64 encoding for image. store base64 encoding for image as string in DB. and then retrieve the image encoding as string and convert it to base64 to get image back. that will help you.

Comment: @ArmaanStranger
k,i will try and post u on the update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find a method to save the image to the database so I started to save the image directly to the internal memory,this is not the answer for the question but may give some ideas to others who also don't have any idea to do...

To save into internal memory...

```
   File fileWithinMyDir = getApplicationContext().getFilesDir();  
    try 
          {
              StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
              .permitAll().build();
          StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy); 
           URL url = new URL("http://t2.gstatic.com  /images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQjZgUffqqe2mKKb5VOrDNd-ZxD7sJOU7WAHlFAy6PLbtXpyQZYdw");
           File file = new File( fileWithinMyDir.getAbsolutePath()  + "/" +"sun.jpg");
           URLConnection ucon = url.openConnection();
           InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();
           BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
           ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(50);
           int current = 0;
           while ((current = bis.read()) != -1) 
           {
            baf.append((byte) current);
           }

           FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
           fos.write(baf.toByteArray());
           fos.close();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            Log.e("download", e.getMessage());
        }
```

To load image from internal memory..

```
 StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
          .permitAll().build();
           StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy); 
          mImgView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.mImgView1); 

          Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileWithinMyDir.getAbsolutePath()  + "/" +"sunn"+".file extension");
          mImgView1.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

This is for newer android's that show error due to " android.os.networkonmainthreadexception"

u can also use AsyncTask if u want to solve the problem...

Answer (score 2):

try below code..

```
byte[] Image_bytes = cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndex("image"));
ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgIcon);
iv.setImageBitmap(new ImageConversation().convertArrayToBmp(Image_bytes));
```

...

```
public Bitmap convertArrayToBmp(byte[] array) {
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(array, 0, array.length);
    return bitmap ;
}
```

use following loop

```
c.moveToFirst();
while(!c.isAfterLast()) {
    byte[] blob = c.getBlob(c.getColumnIndex("image"));
    ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgIcon);
    iv.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(blob, 0,blob.length));
    c.moveToNext()
}
```

Comment: it shows error on ImageConversation() showing to make a new class

Comment: check your do while loop..may be it never ends.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing something like this -

If you are storing your image as String in database

```
 if(image.isEmpty())
  {
   System.out.println("is empty image");

  }
  else
  {
   byte[] decodedByte = Base64.decode(image, 0);
   Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedByte, 0,
     decodedByte.length);
   iv.setImageBitmap(bm);
  }
```